# Capitalize article title in latex

Tags: latex, biblatex

I have a `sample.bib` with a `main.tex` as below, using `Chicago Style`. I was wondering if there is a way to see the `title` with all capital letters `A Formula for the {E}uler Characteristic of Singular Hypersurfaces` in the References. It may be the syle of the .bib [as mentioned here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file) but I was wondering if it can be changed. Many thanks in advance.

main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{sample}

\begin{document}
\title{The Chicago Citation Style with biblatex}
\author{WriteLaTeX}
\maketitle

\section{Demonstration}

 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \autocite{PP95} Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

sample.bib

```
@article{PP95,
  author = "Adam Parusi\'nski and Piotr Pragacz",
   title = "A formula for the {E}uler characteristic of singular hypersurfaces",
 journal = "American review",
  volume = 4,
    year = 1995,
   pages = "337-351"}
```

Comment: Ask this on latex echange. That's the best place for any latex related questions

Comment: @SeymaKalay Please don't use the `bibtex` tag, you are NOT using bibtex, you are using biblatex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same format we used in your question yesterday for the title:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\DeclareFieldFormat{jtnoformat}{\capitalisewords{#1}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{mag+news+title}{\printfield[noformat]{title}}{\printfield[jtnoformat]{title}}{}{}   

\begin{document}
\title{The Chicago Citation Style with biblatex}
\author{WriteLaTeX}
\maketitle

\section{Demonstration}

 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \autocite{PP95} Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you want to have proper title case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\MFUnocap{a}
\MFUnocap{for}
\MFUnocap{the}
\MFUnocap{of}
\DeclareFieldFormat{jtnoformat}{\capitalisewords{#1}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{mag+news+title}{\printfield[noformat]{title}}{\printfield[jtnoformat]{title}}{}{}   

\begin{document}
\title{The Chicago Citation Style with biblatex}
\author{WriteLaTeX}
\maketitle

\section{Demonstration}

 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \autocite{PP95} Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But, it does not work for this .bib though. should I ask a new question? @article{Butler1998,
    title = {{A note on political risk and the required return on foreign direct investment}},
    year = {1998},
    journal = {Journal of International Business Studies},
    author = {Butler, Kirt C and Joaquin, Domingo Castelo},
    number = {3},
    pages = {599--607},
    volume = {29},
    publisher = {Springer},
    issn = {0047-2506}
}

Comment: @SeymaKalay You can't change this title, the double `{{...}}` prevent it. Double `{{...}}` explicitly are there to keep the capitalisation as it is.

Comment: ahh now I see, it works for  {...}, is there a way to make {{..}} to {...}? or any suggestions?

Comment: @SeymaKalay By fixing your bib file?

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution, @samcarter. It works for me regarding article titles and journal names. But how can we tweak it to also work with book and report titles? I don't see in your code where you are specifying the target to be articles...

Comment: @Daniel Can you please ask a new question, including a [mre] so we have a test document to start with?

Comment: Hi again @samcarter, I've posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75274789/capitalize-article-journal-and-book-titles-in-biblatex-bibliography)