# Capitalize book titles and subtitles in `biblatex` bibliography

Tags: latex, capitalization, biblatex

@samcarter has very helpfully shown how to capitalize article, journal and book titles in biblatex bibliography (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75274789/capitalize-article-journal-and-book-titles-in-biblatex-bibliography)). However, the question remains as to how to capitalize *subtitles* as in this `bib` entry for a book with a title and a subtitle:

```
@Book{Elias2000,
  author =       "Norbert Elias",
  title =        "The civilizing process",
  year =         "2000 [1939]",
  subtitle =     "Sociogenetic and psychogenetic investigations",
  edition =      "Revised",
  publisher =    "Blackwell",
  location =     "Oxford"}
```

In a nutshell, how can we make @samcarter's solution work for the subtitle *Sociogenetic and psychogenetic investigations* as well?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chicago biblatex style seems to use the `stnoformat` field format for the subtitle. You can redefine it like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chicago-authordate, hyperref=auto, bibencoding=inputenc, refsection=chapter, doi=false, url=false, isbn=false, eprint=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel,autostyle=true]{csquotes}

% Capitalize article titles and journal names
\usepackage{mfirstuc} 
\MFUnocap{a}
\MFUnocap{for}
\MFUnocap{the}
\MFUnocap{of}
\MFUnocap{and}
\MFUnocap{con}
\MFUnocap{il}
\DeclareFieldFormat{jtnoformat}{\capitalisewords{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{stnoformat}{\capitalisewords{#1}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{mag+news+title}{\printfield[noformat]{title}}{\printfield[jtnoformat]{title}}{}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{italtitle+stitle}{\printfield[tnoformat]{title}}{\printfield[jtnoformat]{title}}{}{}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{sample.bib}
@Book{Elias2000,
  author =       "Norbert Elias",
  title =        "The civilizing process",
  year =         "2000 [1939]",
  subtitle =     "Sociogenetic and psychogenetic investigations",
  edition =      "Revised",
  publisher =    "Blackwell",
  location =     "Oxford"}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{Elias2000}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Above @samcarter has very helpfully shown how to capitalize article, journal and book titles and subtitles in biblatex bibliography. However, new instances of bibliographic references keep cropping up. For example, I now have a book chapter, so I use the `InBook` type of `bib`entry; but the result is that the chapter title is capitalized, which is what I want, but the book title is not, which is not what I want. My question is, where is the reference document where @samcarter finds how to adjust these options? As usual, thank you very much for your time! Daniel

Comment: I don't think there is a dedicated reference document, I usually look into the source code to see what the field formats are called, e.g. http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/latex/chicago-authordate.bbx

Comment: Thank you @samcarter! I've looked into the  `.bbx` document you've linked to and I've added the line `\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\capitalisewords{#1}}` which does capitalize the book title BUT has the unintended consequence of printing it in regular font, rather than in italics as it was originally and I would like to still have it. How come?

Comment: @Daniel Can you ask a new question?

Comment: thank you @samcarter! You can find the new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75841654/capitalize-and-keep-in-italics-the-main-title-of-an-edited-book-in-biblatex-bibl)